# maven-war-plugin version cause OOM

Tags: maven, out-of-memory, maven-war-plugin

I have a web app built using maven-war-plugin

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/min</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

When I run `maven clean package`, the build runs fine but maven complains the plugin does not have a version. So I add the version to the plugin and it becomes

```
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/min</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

This time I got an OOM error

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ByteArrayOutputStream.needNewBuffer (ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ByteArrayOutputStream.write (ByteArrayOutputStream.java:192)
at org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.write (ThresholdingOutputStream.java:129)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.DeferredScatterOutputStream.writeOut (DeferredScatterOutputStream.java:44)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.StreamCompressor$ScatterGatherBackingStoreCompressor.writeOut (StreamCompressor.java:291)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.StreamCompressor.writeCounted (StreamCompressor.java:273)
```

I add `<argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>` and change MAVEN_OPTS but none of these help.

My Question: Why version number matters and what is the problem if I do not include it? And why this OOM happens even if I add Xmx? Thanks!

P.S., when I am not indicating `version`, maven uses 2.2 for war plugin if that helps.

Comment: Where do you have added the `<argLine>..</argLine>` ? How large will the war become?

Comment: I add the `argLine` in `<configuration>`.  The built war is 140M. When I do not add `version` and build the war successfully, maven report memory usage is ~250M.

Comment: sry, cannot reproduce .., on a file with 140m random bytes, jdk:vendor,(maven?)version? (i tested: oracle_win_jdk_11.0.1_x64, maven 3.5.2)

Comment: this sounds "very like" https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSOURCES-94

Comment: Apache Maven 3.5.2, Oracle JDK 1.8.0_201, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @xerx593 You are right, after switching back to plexus-archiver 2.9.1 the problem is solved. I also tried the latest version (4.1.0) of the archiver but the problem appear again. It seems the new version uses more memory and is slower. If you write your response as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad, that I could help, @Harper! ..but unfortunately I don't know/see/understand all of your (plugin/dependency?) configuration/versioning details ... to post a confident answer ... so thank you for the "accredited rep."!  :)..but maybe a clearer answer with your words!

Comment: ..and as you say "tried the latest version", maybe it has to be re-opened/viewed at maven.org...

Comment: An example project which shows the behaviour would be helpful.